# Why do contains()/indexOf() in Java collections use o.equals(e) and not e.equals(o)?

Tags: java, collections, equals

Why are the methods [`contains()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) and [`indexOf()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29) in the Java collections framework defined using `o.equals(e)` and not `e.equals(o)` (where `o` is the argument of the methods and `e` is the element in the collection)?

Anyone know the reasons of that?

Comment: You really need to clarify this question. What do you mean by `e` and `0`?

Comment: Note that the fact that `o.equals(e)` appears in the API specification does not constrain any implementations to actually implement it that way. They only have to produce the same answer as that would produce. Because equals() is contractually required to be reflexive, they're free to actually implement it in either direction.

Comment: That's a very nice question that i've come across after almost 8 years in java... The way the equals is processed is logic because O is guaranteed NOT to be null, but, it raised problems with my code, because if O is a STRING and ELEMENT is not, then no element is ever found despite ELEMENT overriding equals :\

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because `o` is known not be null, but `e` isn't necessarily. Take this example from the code for `LinkedList`:

```
for (Entry e = header.next; e != header; e = e.next) {
    if (o.equals(e.element))
        return index;
    index++;
}
```

In this example, doing it this way round avoids the need to protect against `e.element` being null for every item in the collection. Here's the full code that takes account of `o` being null:

```
if (o == null) {
    for (Entry e = header.next; e != header; e = e.next) {
        if (e.element == null)
            return index;
        index++;
    }
} else {
    for (Entry e = header.next; e != header; e = e.next) {
        if (o.equals(e.element))
            return index;
        index++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Both `e` and `o` can be `null` (at least in some collections).

Comment: Yes, but that's already been catered for by the time you reach the loop. That's why I say `o` is known not to be null.

Comment: I understood the question to be about the definition of the methods and not so much about the implementation, but looking back at it it could equally well be the other way around ...

Comment: David should have posted the full code of `indexOf`. There you see, that `o` can not be null in that part of the function.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between using `x.equals(y)` and `y.equals(x)` is the following:

If `x` is `null`, `y.equals(x)` would simply return `false` whyle `x.equals(y)` would result in a NullPointerException.

Comment: The way the methods are defined in the Javadoc ensures that `equals()` is never called with a `null` argument and is never called on a `null` reference.

Comment: How can the documentation ensure that I wont call `equals()` with a `null` argument?

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have a collection of *friendly* objects, e.g.

```
class Friendly {
    final int i;
    Friendly( int i ) { this.i = i; }
    public boolean equals( Object o ) {
        return o != null && o instanceof Friendly && ((Friendly)o).i == this.i;
    }
}

java.util.Collection c = new java.util.ArrayList();
for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
    c.add( new Friendly(i) );
```

and you want to insert an *unfriendly* object, which is never to be found in a collection by `contains`:

```
class Unfriendly extends Friendly {
    Unfriendly( int i ) { super(i); }
    public boolean equals( Object o ) { return false; }
}
```

If `contains` called `e.equals(o)` then your sinister plan would fail, as the *friendly* elements already in the collection get to decide whether an *unfriendly* object equals to them or not.
By calling `o.equals(e)` it is the *unfriendly* object passed to `contains` which gets to decide what it wants to be equal to, allowing you to make use of the method overriding facility.

```
System.out.println("contains friendly? " + c.contains(new Friendly(1)));
#> contains friendly? true
System.out.println("contains unfriendly? " + c.contains(new Unfriendly(1)));
#> contains unfriendly? false
```

`contains friendly?` is `true` because we are using `ArrayList`; had we been using `HashSet` or anything hashed, it becomes necessary to specify a `hashCode` method too.

Notice that although the contract for `contains` requires the use of the `equals` method, some implementations may not conform to this, such as `org.eclipse.emf.common.util.BasicEList`, wasting your time by having you figure that out.

In this case you have to do the comparison yourself, e.g.

```
boolean contained = false;
for( Object e : c )
    if( o.equals(e) ) { contained = true; break; }
```